# Relational Query In laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My Code

```php
$videos = ExamVideo::with([
    'user' => function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('user_name', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%');
    }
])->where('is_marked','=', 0)->get();

return $videos;
```

I want to get only those videos where `is_marked` is zero & it's relation `user_name` match my search result.

But I get all the videos which marked is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `with` method is only for [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) and not used to filter your records.

You can accomplish what you want with the `whereHas` method which will perform a query on the relation:

```php
$videos = ExamVideo::whereHas('user', function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('user_name', 'like', "%{$request->search}%");
})->where('is_marked', false)->get();
```

For more information about `whereHas`: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence